# Create a custom edit user form with Devise User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

The main question is: **Can I create a custom edit user form with the user I created from devise with my own controller?**

But here's another question while I was trying to answer the main question: (it would be great if I could get this answered as well) which is: why am I missing a model hash for the strong parameters? here's the situation if you read the following:

What I've done (may be irrelevant but I'm describing it just in case) in my project is I have a custom "users controller" and at a route /users/:username, it displays the user name and some data for a foreign relation.

But on that page, I display the user's username and e-mail and I'm basically trying to include a form along with foreign relation data. Problem is when I use form_for with the @user and only username and e-mail input, I'd expect an **existing :user hash** that goes into the **params.require(:user)** but the user is never passed when I submit the form. Why is that?

Is it because of all the configuration and setup with devise, I have to somehow modify the existing registration edit form rather than create my own form_for with the @user object?

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started? especially https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Comment: yes, i've read it all. so i have the assumption that i can't create a custom edit user form since one already exists but nothing directly tells me that fact. also, im a relative rails beginner so i can't say i fully understand everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rephrased my poor question (it may still look a little off). But anyways, I answered my own question. And the answer is:

"Yes, I can create a custom edit user form with the user with my own controller. But that controller must override and use devise. It cannot be something out of the blank ApplicationController." As for my other question that had to do with what happened with the missing hash, I think I would need to understand rails at a deeper level for that.